# When to use timed cookies over a timed interval in a database

Tags: php, cookies

I'm coming here today to ask the professionals when/how do you(s) make the decision to use a Cookie Expire time over a Timed Access specified by a time and using the clients `$_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'];`?

Just taking a chunk from the php manual about `setcookie();` follows:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
```

According to the manual, this cookie will expire in one hour.. But as we know, cookies can be modified by the client using a range of tools, so if the client (bad person) caught on that the cookie is set to expire, which will either allow access to something, or deny access to something until another event is triggered?

Whereas, something more is to use the time(); function within MySQL and create a Timed row in the Schema table with the clients Public IP address as the identifier.

But the client can browse to the website using a proxy browser/mobile device with a different IP address.

They both use the same concept, of either allowing/denying access after the interval has passed, but can both be bypassed if the client knows their stuff.

So I come back to my overall question, when/how is it possible to tell when it's acceptable to use a timed interval set by a cookie or a database?

Comment: *"with the clients Public IP address as the identifier."* no, never use ip to identify a person.

Comment: @Dagon Why should I not use the IP, because it can't be changed on the fly. Only by navigating to the website under a proxy address or a mobile device?

Comment: 1 IP can be many people, 1 person can use many IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should use combination of both - database to store the data and client's cookies to identify row in the database table.

Using IP address for identification is not very reliable because:

- More clients may have the same IP
- Client's IP address might change randomly (i.e. wifi / gsm connection on the smartphones)

You can also use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) which are probably faster and easier way to store user's information, and if you don't want to manage cookies by yourself, it's a way to go.